# Php REST API from Shopify Order if exist a sub array

Tags: php, json, api, multidimensional-array, shopify

from shopify I GET the orders but the items is in subarrary and I don't know how many item there are

```
$products_obj_url = $api_url . '/admin/api/2022-07/orders.json?status=any&limit=250&since_id='.$id;}
    $products_content = @file_get_contents( $products_obj_url );
    $products_json = json_decode( $products_content, true );
    $orders = $products_json['orders'];

    foreach($orders as $orders){   
            echo "<tr>
            echo "<td>".$conto."</td>";
            echo "<td>". $orders['id']. "</td>";                
            echo "<td>". $orders['line_items'][0]['id']. "</td>";
            echo "<td>". $orders['line_items'][0]['name']. "</td>";
            echo "<td>". $orders['line_items'][0]['price']. "</td>";
            echo "<td>". $orders['line_items'][0]['product_id']. "</td>";
            echo "<td>". $orders['line_items'][0]['sku']. "</td>";
            echo "<td>". $orders['line_items'][0]['quantity']. "</td></tr>";}
```

the problem is that in this mode I see only the first items... how I can create "for cicle" to see all items.. I don't know how many items I can to have.

Comment: Be careful when doing something like `foreach($orders as $orders){` as it uses the same name.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a nested loop to iterate over all the line items for each order.

```php
foreach($orders as $order){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$conto."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$order['id']."</td>";
    
    // iterate over all line items for this order
    foreach ($order['line_items'] as $item) {
        echo "<td>".$item['id']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$item['name']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$item['price']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$item['product_id']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$item['sku']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$item['quantity']."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
}
```

This will print out a row for each line item, for each order. The inner loop will iterate over all line items for the current order, regardless of how many there are.